Pyspark: Unable to unzip files recursively and copy into another folder in databricks
I am currently trying to unzip files recursively from one folder(source folder) and copy all the unzipped files into the destination folder using databricks(pyspark). The destination path is still empty even after running this code:
import os
import zipfile
from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils

local_file_path = dbutils.fs.ls('abfss://storage@container.dfs.core.windows.net/zipped_folder')
dest_file_path = dbutils.fs.ls('abfss://storage@container.dfs.core.windows.net/unzipped_folder')

def unzip_file(file_path, extract_path):
    # Copy the file to local file system
    local_path = "/tmp/" + os.path.basename(file_path)
    dbutils.fs.cp(file_path, "file:" + local_path, recurse=True)

    # Unzip the file on local file system
    with zipfile.ZipFile(local_path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall("/tmp")

    # Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
    dbutils.fs.mkdirs(extract_path)

    # Copy the unzipped files to the destination folder
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/tmp"):
        for filename in files:
            if filename != os.path.basename(file_path):
                local_file = os.path.join(root, filename)
                dest_file = extract_path + "/" + os.path.relpath(local_file, "/tmp")
                try:
                    dbutils.fs.cp("file:" + local_file, dest_file, recurse=True)  # Remove 'overwrite=True'
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error copying file: {e}")

    # Remove the temporary files
    dbutils.fs.rm(local_path, recurse=True)

# Call the unzip_file function with the appropriate arguments
if dest_file_path:
    unzip_file(str(local_file_path[0].path), str(dest_file_path[0].path))

The Destination folder is empty. Is there any code changes that I need to do?
